# How to get Swedish sort order for strings

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I am having a problem sorting Swedish strings.

I am having problems with the following characters: v, w, å, ä, ö.

```
new[] { "ö", "ä", "å", "wa", "va", "wb", "vb", "a"  }
.OrderBy(x => x, new CultureInfo("sv-SE").CompareInfo.GetStringComparer(CompareOptions.None))
```

Expected:
a, va, vb, wa, wb, å, ä, ö

Actual:
a, va, wa, vb, wb, å, ä, ö

Is the there any option to make it sort the strings as expected?

Comment: Have you read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/locale/sorting-and-string-comparison

Comment: From what I see in Wikipedia, this used to be the correct order, so possibly Windows/.NET didn't follow the recent change?

Comment: As far as I can tell v and w are being treated interchangeably by .NET.  I understand that the sort order has recently changed in 2006 according to Svenska Akademiens ordlista 13th edition.  We might have to investigate the [.NET source.](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/) to be sure.

Comment: As a work-around I have switched to the culture se-SE (Sami) just for sorting alphabetic strings correctly.

Comment: @OskarSjöberg you can always answer your own question if you solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a work-around I have switched to the culture se-SE (Sami) just for sorting alphabetic strings correctly while I wait for the .NET sorting rules to be updated.

Update:

Here is the github issue:
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/37753

Update2:

The issue is not with .NET, it is the sorting rules defined in the underlying operating system. This error is only present on Windows.

Comment: This isn't fixed in .NET Core 3.0 preview 5 either. This should probably be raised as an issue

Comment: Good idea! I have raised an issue now, see link above.