# OrderBy does not work on my computer only

Tags: c#, sorting, globalization

We have a old legacy db gen tool for database first. I get changes to stuff without actual changes. I have boiled it down to sorting of columns.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("sv-SE");
var sortThis = new[] { "VatNumber", "VisiAvtalsnummerCompanies", "WinZipPassword" }
    .OrderBy(s => s, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
    .ToList();
```

Output should be "VatNumber", "VisiAvtalsnummerCompanies", "WinZipPassword", in swedish culture V comes before W in the alphabet.

But on my computer the output is "VatNumber", "WinZipPassword", "VisiAvtalsnummerCompanies"

Servers on C# fiddle outputs correct

https://dotnetfiddle.net/sXJjD6

edit:

```
StringComparer.Create(new CultureInfo("sv-SE"), true)
                .Compare("V", "W"); // -1  correct

StringComparer.Create(new CultureInfo("sv-SE"), true)
                .Compare("VB", "WA"); // 1  incorrect
```

Comment: What happens if you replace `StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` with `StringComparer.Create(new CultureInfo("sv-SE"), true)`?

Comment: If it's sorting V - W - V then it's not sorting. That seems improbable, but when something impossible seems to be happening there's always an incorrect assumption. My best guess is that it's sorting by string length. That means maybe the code executing locally isn't what you though it was.

Comment: @41686d6564 no difference

Comment: Just a thought. In most cases the culture settings that are used are retrieved from your machine's regional settings. So if you have specified that your machine region is `sv-SE`, but you have overruled these settings, then there is your difference. Have you compared that with someone else's machine?

Comment: My OS has en-SV (english install swedish formating)

Comment: I asked my colleague to change to en-SV still works for him

Comment: Its not related to length, like I said above. Other machines return correct. On my machine this returns 1 which is not right, StringComparer.Create(new CultureInfo("sv-SE"), true)
                .Compare("Vis", "Win");

Comment: added more info in question

Comment: Sometimes there are hidden non-printable characters in your source code - especially if the characters came from a web page via copy-paste.  Can you double-check that the strings are encoded correctly with no hidden characters?  (I ask this because the fiddle was not character-for-character identical with the code in this post -- there were comments added so they are ostensibly not identical.)

Comment: Compare Windows versions? This sort of stuff comes from information stored in the Windows registry (at least for .NET Framework), which can (and does!) change between minor versions.

Comment: Could this be relevant? [Culture sv-SE sort order for strings does not handle the order of v and w correctly](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29592)?  It just reinforces that it might be something about the OS that is the culprit.

Comment: Then we should see same output on all machines, Which we dont. My machine is doing it wrong while my coworkes machines are doing it right. I'm a consultant and are using Windows 10 Enterprise, the other are employees and are on Windows 10 Pro. They have sv-SE default in windows while I have en-SE. But they have tried to change to en-SE without problem. Still works for them

Comment: @Anders Check the actual [Windows version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/) as well, e.g. "2004" or "20H2". I've seen differences in culture stuff even between minor versions.

Comment: Yeah, I'm upgrading from 1909 to 2004 as we speak

Comment: Look at Using statements at top of module.  Missing using System.Collections.Generic; and using System.Collections;

Comment: @jdweng That's unrelated to the question....

Comment: @canton7 : Don't you need the library for it to work?

Comment: 2004 did fix it. Unbelievable

Comment: @jdweng The question presumes that the code runs, and is asking why the sort order is odd. The question is not "this code doesn't compile", it's "this code obviously compiles and runs, but why does it produce this output". Telling them how to get it to run doesn't help - it's obvious the OP can *already* run it. OP also links to dotnetfiddle where they've included the right using statements, so they obviously know they're required

Comment: @Anders Knew it! We once had a case where a minor version update introduced a space after the currency symbol for one particular locale, which broke the build, but wasn't reproducible on developer machines...

Comment: This mus be a problem for lots of Swedish programmers out there :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to 2006, it seems that V and W were sorted equally in Swedish: it seems Swedish doesn't really use W (except in names and imported words), and V and W were sometimes used interchangeably, so this sorting order was chosen to reduce confusion [1].

Back in 2006, the 13th edition of SAOL (Svenska Akademiens OrdLista; the reference dictionary for the Swedish language) declared that W was a letter in its own right, and it started to be sorted as a separate letter to V.

CLDR, the Unicode Common Locale Data Repository which defines this sort of stuff, introduced two collations for Swedish: "standard" and "reformed". They changed the default collation to "reformed" back in 2007 [2], which would have affected anything using the CLDR as its reference.

Windows integrated the International Components for Unicode (ICU), which uses CLDR data, in the 1903 update. However, this should only affect .NET 5: earlier .NET version should still be using the National Language Support (NLS) libraries [3].

I haven't been able to find any data on changes to the NLS between version 1909 and 2004. It's possible that they finally caught up with the CLDR, I don't know. There were some breaking changes to sorting back in Windows 7, but I can't find anything since [4]. If you're targetting .NET 5, and upgraded from 1903, then I could explain it.

If you're targetting .NET 5+, or running on Linux, you should have been using CLDR data all along.

[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swedish_alphabet#Uncommon_letters
[2]: https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/commit/aaa134f4f74db91b781be1c8b9d9e9f1fd123c0e
[3]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/globalization-localization/globalization-icu
[4]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/win7appqual/nls-sorting-changes

Other random links which I came across, but didn't form part of my answer:

1. https://unicode-org.atlassian.net/browse/CLDR-1035#icft=CLDR-1035
2. [https://unicode-org.atlassian.net/browse/CLDR-2143?jql=text%20~%20%22swedish%20collation%22](https://unicode-org.atlassian.net/browse/CLDR-2143?jql=text%20%7E%20%22swedish%20collation%22)
3. https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=9724
4. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=17005
5. [Sort list of tuples considering locale (swedish ordering)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546822/sort-list-of-tuples-considering-locale-swedish-ordering)
6. http://www.softwolves.pp.se/misc/arkiv/sv/18/9009.html
7. [How to get Swedish sort order for strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56188303/how-to-get-swedish-sort-order-for-strings/56188532)
8. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29592

Comment: On 1909 I got the problem both on full framework 4.8 and on  .NET Core 3.1. 2004 update fixes both.

Comment: The NLS must have finally updated to the reformed collation in 2004 then, but I can't find any change notes actually saying this.