# Why do Linq's OrderBy not always adhere to CurrentCulture?

Tags: c#, linq, wcf, globalization, cultureinfo

I have a problem where doing an `OrderBy` on a `List<object>` containing strings is returning different results in different environments, even though the CurrentCulture is set the same.

Example:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("sv-SE");
var people = new List<object>{"Åke", "Adam", "Bengan"};
return people.OrderBy(p => p);
```

The names are in Swedish and should be ordered:

1. Adam
2. Bengan
3. Åke

This example is very much simplified, and I need to use a generic data type `object` for the list.

The code is run inside a .NET 4.8 **WCF**-service, and I've tried enforcing the culture in many different ways. For now on my machine (Win 10) the WCF service returns US-sort: 1. Adam 2. Åke 3. Bengan, but when I write a unit test, the code returns the correct Swedish-sort. I also have a couple of external test-servers where the result differ, some return the correct Swedish sort from the WCF-service and others not. I need a way of strictly enforcing the culture for sorting.

What more could impact the way of sorting? I have read up on [SortVersion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.sortversion?view=netframework-4.8) but can not find out how to apply it to my example.

Cheers!

**UPDATE 1**

When running: `RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription` both the unit test and WCF service returns: `.NET Framework 4.8.4420.0`.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("sv-SE");
Comparer<object>.Default.Compare("Åke", "Bengan");
```

The unit test returns `1` (which is correct), the WCF service returns: `-1`.

**UPDATE 2**

Regarding versions. All machines have .NET Framework 4.8 installed.

OrderBy with Swedish letters **works** on this version:

- Windows Server 2016 Standard

But **doesn't work** on:

- Windows 10 Enterprise version: 21H2
- Windows Server 2019 version: 2004

We have no other machines to reproduce this bug on at this time.
There must be a way to enforce the culture specific sort on all machines?

Comment: I have a vague recollection that the sorting of Å in Swedish was something which was changed by Unicode at some point. This isn't to do with the CurrentCulture per se -- it's to do with the culture information built into Windows (.NET 4.8 used the NLS). It's likely your machines are running slightly different versions of Windows?

Comment: Hmm, no I'm thinking of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64753140/orderby-does-not-work-on-my-computer-only/64756277#64756277), which was between V and W. It looks like both the [reformed and standard collations](https://www.unicode.org/cldr/cldr-aux/charts/27/collation/sv.html) sort Å after Z

Comment: Can you confirm the .NET versions used for the WCF service and the unit tests? Do they both target .NET 4.8? Likewise the external test servers

Comment: Btw, you should be able to cut linq out of the question, by just doing e.g. `Comparer<object>.Default.Compare("Åke", "Bengan")`, which should be equivalent to `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.Compare("Åke", "Bengan")`

Comment: @canton7 Thanks, I updated the question. They run the same .NET-version. There must be something inside the running process (WCF or VS Test) that differ?

Comment: What about OS versions / patches?

Comment: @canton7 this last update is on my machine only, running the WCF-server and running the unit test. Windows 10 Enterprise version: 21H2 OS build: 19044.1586.

Comment: So all of the machines involved are all on 19044.1586, every single one of them? I want to see if there's some sort of pattern between OS / .NET versions, and whether Å is sorted before or after Z

Comment: @canton7 ah sry, I was stuck on WCF and unit test returning different. A server that works is a patched Windows Server 2016 Standard.

Comment: Can you look at all of the servers you ran this test on? E.g. draw up a table of .NET Version + OS version vs whether it works or not. These sorts of locale/collation issues are normally do to with the Unicode data built into .NET / Windows.

Comment: Have you tried `people.OrderBy(p => p).ToList()`? `IEnumerable` does not mean that everything is sorted right now.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Thanks, yes, I've tried ToList, see my latest update without a list as well.

Comment: @canton7 Thanks a lot! I updated my question with UPDATE 2. Unfortunately that is all data I have as of now.

Comment: I remember a situation somehow like your problem! When we want to compare an RTL language and have no idempotent results. We changed windows regional and language formats and settings, and the problem was solved. That was for .Net Framework 2.0 on Windows Forms, so I do not remember the exact settings, but it is worth trying.